# Dynamic ng-model for directive re-use

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I have a page with one controller and three tabs, each tab shows its own ng-grid and a text box for filtering the visible rows (not the built-in filterbox).

I created this simple directive for the filter box that I want to use on each tab (as I have done on other pages).

```
myDirectives.directive('myGridFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'filterTemplate.html'
  }
});
```

This is filterTemplate.html:

```
<label input="filterLabel" for="filterBox">Filter: </label>
<input id="filterBox" type="text" placeholder="type filter here" ng-model="gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText" />
```

I have created three ng-grids (`$scope.gridOptions_1`, `$scope.gridOptions_2` and `$scope.gridOptions_3`) with each referencing the appropriate dataset for its tab.

My question is, how can I modify the directive so I can specify the `ng-model` to be `gridOptions_1.filterOptions.filterText` vs. `gridOptions_2.filterOptions.filterText` vs. `gridOptions_3.filterOptions.filterText` vs. plain old `gridOption.filterOptions.filterText`?

Here is what I tried, without success...

- Added `scope: { subgrid: '@subgrid' }` to the directive
- Changed the template file to have:

  - `ng-model="gridOptions{{subgrid}}.filterOptions.filterText"`
  - `ng-model="gridOptions[subgrid].filterOptions.filterText"`
  - `ng-model="gridOptions[scope.subgrid].filterOptions.filterText"`
- Changed the reference to the directive on my page to be `<myGridFilter subgrid="_1"></myGridFilter>`

I would also like to be able to reuse the directive for the generic `gridOptions` case on other pages, so I also tried `{{subgrid||''}}` in the template, but did not go further in trying to accomodate a default case of '' until I figure out how to get the dynamic `ng-model` working first...

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply add `scope: { subgrid: '=subgrid' }` to the directive and make sure you call the directive with the attribute: `<my-grid-filter sub-grid="gridOptions_1"></my-grid-filter>`. 
(You tried with `@subgrid`, but `@` is for text attributes while `=` is for actual binding between attributes and directive scope).

Comment: You can also define it in the html element. Just write subgrid="subgrid".

Comment: @Yann, that makes sense (`=` vs. `@`), thanks; however, I still can't seem to get `subgrid` plugged into the template...the `ng-model` just shows up in the source as `[subgrid]` or `{{subgrid}}` (see my second bullet in the original post)

Comment: Doh! @Yann's answer works...the template just needs to say `ng-model="subgrid.filterOptions.filterText"` (I was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be). Thanks again!